# Python error : Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, file-io

Python error : Python ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

I am trying code

```
import random

with open("GoneGirlSW.txt", "r") as f,open('trainData.txt','w') as   trainFile,open('testData.txt','w') as testFile:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    random.shuffle(data)
    train_data = data[:50]
    test_data = data[50:]

    trainFile.write(str(train_data))
    testFile.write(str(test_data))
```

But it is giving error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainTest.py", line 9, in <module>
    trainFile.write(str(train_data))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: Looks like " trainFile.write(str(train_data))" is out side "with".

Comment: "with" automatically closes the file once it is outside it's scope.

Comment: Perhpas you have edited the code in response to my answer (or somebody else did)? I doubt the version you currently list will actually demonstrate the problem you report ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file is closed automatically when a with/as statement is completed. In your case, the with/as statement is completed immediately due to a lack of indentation. The code should read:

```
 import random

with open("GoneGirlSW.txt", "r") as f, open('trainData.txt','w') as trainFile, open('testData.txt','w') as testFile:
  data = f.read().split('\n')
  random.shuffle(data)
  train_data = data[:50]
  test_data = data[50:]

  trainFile.write(str(train_data))
  testFile.write(str(test_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know, since your code doesn't appear correctly indented. I am assuming this is because you aren't yet familiar with question editing.

The purpose of the `with` statement is to let you execute code in a known context. In the case of opening files, it guarantees that the file is closed at the end of the indented suite. So I am guessing that you haven't indented the last two statements so they are part of the code covered by the `with`.

Answer (score 0):

Lines of code after with statement should be indented